# TypeScript, type for json response Object in Object[]

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have the response from API. I need processing that response and get values from that.
I can understand which type I should use for that.
Also when I tried this.filters[key] I fetched error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)
```

My object from response:

```
"OneType": {
    "OnePart": {
        "Values": [
            "codes..",
            "codes..",
            "codes..",
            "codes.."
        ],
        "Values2": [
            "codes..",
            "codes..",
            "codes..",
            "codes.."
        ]
    },
    "SecondPart": {
        "Values": [
            "codes..",
            "codes..",
            "codes..",
            "codes.."
        ],
        "Values2": [
            "codes..",
            "codes..",
            "codes..",
            "codes.."
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried make type, but still have a error about key.

```
type FilterArray = { [key: string]: [] };
```

[The error in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPmEa.png)

***I want to note that each value can have multiple values, like the first one (OneType, TwoType...) and (FirstPart / Second/ third..)***

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, are you looking for a proper type of your response (something like this: https://tsplay.dev/w6LYym)? Can you provide the piece of code that throws the error, so everyone has a context on what you try to achieve?

Comment: what about this ? :
type FilterArray ={"OneType": { [part: string]: { [values: string]: string[] } }};

Comment: @r3dst0rm I attached a screenshot to the post. 
I want to note that each value can have multiple values, like the first one (OneType, TwoType...) and (FirstPart / Second/ third..)

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER, I looked at something else:
type MyTuple<T> = [string, { [key: string]: any }, T[]];

Comment: but i can't get rid of this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution.
Everything can be easy.

We make JSON type and if we want to get an object by key we can use:

```
type JSONValue =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | JSONObject
    | JSONArray;

interface JSONObject {
    [x: string]: JSONValue;
}

interface JSONArray extends Array<JSONValue> { }
```

Receive:

```
const myObject: JSONArray = {
 first: {
     second: {
       third: ['1','2']
     }, 
     secondSecond: {
       ...
     },
   ...
 }
};
const result = myObject[key as keyof JSONValue];
```